# Futures prices reported on websites and media

Tags: futures

You would often see a list of futures prices on stock websites. For example, on [Seeking Alpha](https://seekingalpha.com):

[image: Seeking Alpha futures prices]

What are the expiry dates of the futures they are referring to, particularly for the Dow, S&P and Nasdaq futures?

Comment: Could you give us the link to this stock website?

Comment: https://seekingalpha.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if there's "fine print" or a link on the site that tells what the expiry is. There's not a "standard" expiry for futures, so the site *should* give an indication of what futures contract is used.

[CNN Money](https://money.cnn.com/data/premarket/), for example, list this below the futures quotes:

> Futures based on December 2020 contract.

My guess is they use a rolling monthly or quarterly contract to represent a "near-time" futures quote.

It's also possible that the prices are derived from other sources (the link you added shows "Real-Time CFD Derived") or that they are quoting a "fair value" based on one or more actual futures prices. The "fair value" of an index is the discounting of the futures price to the present based on current interest rates and adjusting for dividends. It's supposed to give an indication of what the index *should* be based on the futures quote.

The bottom line is that there's no "industry standard" for these quotes - without an explanation of the context you're left to speculate.

Comment: The description for [INDU - Dow Jones Futures](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/INDU) says: "Real-Time CFD Derived".

Comment: @Flux Thanks - added.